# How to create horizontal list view with faded image by Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need a horizontal list view in the flutter , that according to the image below, the first item is empty and the image is visible in the background, when the second item starts scrolling, the background image disappears and when the item returns to its place , The image also returns to the original state.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I published Package [(flutter_faded_list)](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_faded_list) for designing this UI on the pub.dev website.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some code here.
The vertical `listview` you can get with the `SingleChildScroolView` changing the axis to vertical and placing a Column inside.
To the empty space on last item, place a `Sizedbox` as last widget inside Column.
Place a `ScrollController` on the `SingleChildScroolView` with a listener, and when the controller reach the maximum just fade in the background image.
Its not hard, just need some code.